# Telethon Python TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hash'

Tags: python, telegram

hi i use this code for scraping members in telegram groups but error for GetDialogsRequest
i use hash_id and remove hash as request but not worked
parametr hash is argument in GetDialogsRequest

other parametrs

offset_date
offset_id
offset_peer
limit
hash
exclude_pinned
folder_id

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import csv

api_id = 11111
api_hash = '2328378db8c4cf3a74cd1240eb16272f3'
phone = '+44000000000'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))


chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if user.first_name:
            first_name= user.first_name
        else:
            first_name= ""
        if user.last_name:
            last_name= user.last_name
        else:
            last_name= ""
        name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
        writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id])      
print('Members scraped successfully.')
```

and get result

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hash'
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the error, `GetDialogsRequest.__init__` [does have](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_dialogs.html) a `hash` argument.

Perhaps you are using an older version of telethon. Try to upgrade it.